# How to delete excel column by header name?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, windows, worksheet

I doing a c# windows application project. It's will read all excel header and paste to checkedListBox. After selected items of checkedListBox. It's will remove column header and rows from excel(like your click on header column of excel and press delete button)

could you help me please :'(

[image: Select header name for delete]

[image: Dalete this column]
[image: Display result]

```html
public void OpenFile()
        {
            Excel excel = new Excel(@"D:\Book2.xlsx", 1);

            for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
               
                label1.Text = "Total : " + i.ToString() + " Column";

                
                label2.Text = excel.ReadCell(0, i);
                checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(i, label2.Text);
            }


      
        }
```

```html
class Excel
    {
        string path = "";
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;

        public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
        }

        public string ReadCell(int i, int j)
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            if(ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
            {
                return ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Guys, this is not an automation question.

Answer (score 0):

What Excel framework/library you're using?

Have you tried with:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
...
ws.DeleteColumn(Int32 columnIndex);
```

You can attach an event handler to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx

And use Tag property of CheckBox to communicate the Column index.

Something like:

```
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck;

private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(Object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
CheckBox checkedBox = (CheckBox) sender;
Int32 columnIndex = (Int32) checkedBox.Tag;

ws.DeleteColumn(columnIndex);

}
```

Comment: I'm using this library.

using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Could you Explain me about "ws".

Comment: the 'ws' is your Worksheet ws;

Instead of calling Interop.Excel (meaning you must have Microsoft Excel installed on the PC where your application is running) consider using an open source library like: ClosedXML or EPPlus (you can easly add them using NuGet Package Manager in your VS).
However, APIs of all three options should be very similar. If you go to EPPlus, I can help you 100%, because I'm using it a lot.
(when you use EPPlus or ClosedXML you can run on any OS, and without having Microsoft Office installed)

Comment: Or wait, you actually want to automate Excel while it is opened in another window or you want to edit the file?
If you are doing automation then I'm useless as have no experience with that kind of job.

Comment: Thank you brother, I'm choose EPPlus to be my library and could you give your email or other to contact with me?

Thank you again for your solution. It's very helpful.

Comment: goran.grubic  et gmail.com

Comment: My project isn't automation. It's manual control.

Comment: You can mail me the project or this particular .cs file, I'll fix it and post here the working example. (if you send the project I'll add the Nuget package). Send the project via weTransfer, as my GMail will not allow any exe (you probably have one in /Debug/Bin folder